# English Morpho-Syntactic Parsing (Shakespeare)

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Could anybody give me a hand with the morpho-syntactic parsing of the following lines from Shakespeare?

> From fairest creatures we desire increase,
>   That thereby beauty’s rose might never die,
>   But as the riper should by time decease,
>   His tender heir might bear his memory:

Comment: The first and fourth lines have main clauses, and the second and third subordinate clauses. The inflected verbs in each line are *desire*, *might*, *should*, and *might*. No derivational morphology to speak of. Subjects are *we*, *beauty's rose*, *the riper*, and *his tender heir*, respectively .

Answer (score 1):

My contemporary interpretation:

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

**We hope for more beautiful things**

**So in that way the height of beauty remains alive forever.**

**Although he who matures must eventually die,**

**His own child would perhaps share a similar beauty.**

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

From fairest creatures we desire increase

--We hope (desire) for more (increase) beautiful things (from fairest creatures)

That thereby beauty’s rose might never die

--So in that way (thereby) the height of beauty (the rose) remains alive forever (might never die)

But as the riper should by time decease

--Although he who matures (the riper) must eventually die (should by time decease),

His tender heir might bear his memory.

--His own child (tender heir) would perhaps (might) share of similar beauty (bear his memory).